# Bootstrap addClass not working in Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've come back to web development after a lengthly lay off, I'm using bootstrap and creating a simple contact form. If there is an error with validation I want to add a couple of classes to make the form element turn red and put the little cross in the input.

I've used the examples from the bootstrap site and I get it to work fine. As soon as I put the content into a form the addClass doesn't stick. The input flashes red and goes back to the grey border. I've stripped back my whole html to check it isn't anything else I've done and have narrowed the error down to the  tags.

Any help greatly appreciated. PS my first post on here, apologies if I've missed anything

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Form</title>
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
        
        <style type="text/css">
        
            #emailError{
                
                display: none;
            }
        
        </style>
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
          <form> 


            <div id="emailDiv" class="form-group">
              <label class="form-control-label" for="inputDanger1">Input with danger</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email">
              <div class="form-control-feedback" id="emailError">Sorry, that username's taken. Try another?</div>
              <small class="form-text text-muted">Example help text that remains unchanged.</small>
            </div>

            <div class="form-element">
                <input type="submit" value="Sign Up" id="submitBtn">
            </div>
           </form>  
        </div>
        
                <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        
        <script type="text/javascript">
            

            $("#submitBtn").click(function(){
                
                $("#emailError").show();
                $("#emailDiv").addClass("has-danger");
                $("#email").addClass("form-control-danger");
            });
            
        </script>
    
    
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not sure I understand, you submit the form so the page is refreshing. Shouldn't you return false to prevent the submission if you found an error (Or add `e` to the callback and use `e.preventDefault();` to stop the click event?

Comment: I've not got that far. Trying to get the classes to be added first.

Comment: Try to replace `$("#submitBtn").click(function(){` with `$("#submitBtn").click(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); ...`

Comment: I'm with you now. It's me being stupid. The page refreshes on the on the submit button. That's my next challenge!!!

Comment: You're not being stupid, you're just learning something new. Please read @Michael's answer and it should help you better understand what you need to do. You will be able to accept it after 15 minutes since you posted your question (Assuming it solved your problem)

Comment: Last time I wrote a web page, HTML was version 1. It's changed a lot!!!!! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @AlonEitan said, you need to disable the default action of the form, which is to submit the form and that will reload the page. You can disable the action with `e.preventDefault()` or `return false`. You can disable it conditionally if you find errors, or you can disable it by default, then manually submit once the form is validated. Here's an example.

```
$("#submitBtn").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  if (there are errors) {
    $("#emailError").show();
    $("#emailDiv").addClass("has-danger");
    $("#email").addClass("form-control-danger");
  } else {
    $('#formId').submit();
  }
});
```

Comment: One slight issue. Followed your example, but the form doesn't submit. Checked that it enters the 'else' part of the if statement. Any ideas?

Comment: @Neil should be pretty straight forward. Sounds like a new issue. If you can't figure it out, I would make a new post.

Comment: `$(this)` is the button, and not the form

Comment: @AlonEitan shoot you're right! I was thinking the event handler was on the form handling `submit`.

Comment: @Neil updated my answer. You just need to either change the parent `$("#submitBtn").click()` to `$('#formId').on('submit',function() {})`, and then `$(this).submit()` will work. Or you can change `$(this).submit()` to `$('#formId').submit()`. Where `#formId` is the `id` of your form.

Comment: Thanks! Will look at that in a bit.